# OpenCV: getting error for resizing- 1428: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0

Tags: python, opencv

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=scaling_factor, fy=scaling_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

> 1428: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0

Comment: Can you edit you question with proper formatting, a context, a real question...

Answer (score 1):

The error is suggesting that the `frame` you extracted from the camera has zero size. So it is recommended to check the size and data of `frame` from `cap.read()`
before doing any processing.